# how to loop in queue over k out of n options in java

Tags: java

I need to calculate in java the sum of each possibility of k numbers out of n numbers in queue or priority queue.

Comment: What do you have done so far?

Comment: If you search for "java iterate over queue" you will find different ways of doing this. It depends on how you implemented your queue.

Comment: a flow of n' integers or doubles is inserted (not sorted) into the queue, and user send me integer (k')  than I need to calculate sum of each possibility from all options of choosing k' out of n. i know how to use queue tools but i can't see how to pass over all these options. thx

Comment: i dont know n' or k' before user sending is data so i need general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I create a queue with n = 7 items.  Take a look at my method "findSumOfFirst(int k)".
If this isn't quite what you're looking for, at least it may help with loops/priority queues.

If you need help with Priority Queues: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

```
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.PriorityQueue;

    public class QueueReader {
        static PriorityQueue<Double> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Double>() {
            /**
             * Order the larger double first.
             *
             * @param o1
             *              First double to be compared
             * @param o2
             *              Second double to be compared
             * @return
             */
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                if(o1 > o2) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (o1 < o2) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Adds 7 doubles
            queue.add(0.3);
            queue.add(0.1);
            queue.add(0.1);
            queue.add(0.2);
            queue.add(0.05);
            queue.add(0.05);
            queue.add(0.2);

            int k = 4;
            int n = queue.size();
            double answer = findSumOfFirst(k);
            System.out.println(answer);
        }

        public static double findSumOfFirst(int k)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                sum += queue.poll();
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }
```

Comment: mathematically there are n!/(k!(n-k)!) possibilities, i'm looking for a general way to pass over all these options. thx

Comment: meaning that for the above sample where n=7 and k=4 there are 35 options, i need theme all.